# Como acessar atributos da classe pai em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Como faço para acessar os atributos da classe pai uma vez que instanciei o filho?

Acesso direto `$Filho->atributoPai` não funciona.

Acesso pela função `$Filho->getterPai` não funciona.

Para cada filho herdado devo fazer *getters* pros atributos de seu pai?

```
<?php

    class Pessoa {
        function __construct($nome, $sexo, $idade) {
            $this->nome = $nome;
            $this->sexo = $sexo;
            $this->idade = $idade;
        }
        function getNome() {
            return $this->nome;
        }
        private $nome;
        private $sexo;
        private $idade;
    }
    class Amigo extends Pessoa {
        function __construct($nome, $sexo, $idade, $diaDoAniversario) {
            parent::__construct($nome, $sexo, $idade);
            $this->diaDoAniversario = $diaDoAniversario;
        }
        private $diaDoAniversario;
    }

    $joao = new Amigo("Jonis", "masc", 20, 30);
    echo "Nome: $joao->nome";  // Notice: Undefined property: Amigo::$nome
    echo "Nome: $joao->getNome()"; // Undefined property: Amigo::$getNome

?>
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Um dos problemas é que não pode ficar forçando uma expressão complexa dentro de uma *string*, tem que fazer concatenação, ou com chaves.

Também se deseja acessar o campo ([não chamo de atributo porque não tem documentação que diz isso em nenhuma linguagem *mainstream* que se preocupa em definir as coisas de maneira correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) então precisa torná-lo público, caso contrário nem no objeto da classe superior poderá acessá-lo.

Pra falar a verdade não sei se deveria fazer isto em PHP. Linguagens de *script* não são adequadas para sistemas complexos. É como usar OOP em microsserviços, se realmente os serviços são micro, e um dos motivos de fazerem isto é fazer com que o código não tenha complexidade, então OOP é desnecessário, que é um estilo para organizar complexidade. Mas em geral as pessoas vão adotando as coisas sem pensar no que estão fazendo e o porquê de adotaram aquilo.

Aliás, a classe superior não deveria ser instanciada, portanto deveria ser `abstract`.

```
class Pessoa {
    function __construct($nome, $sexo, $idade) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
        $this->idade = $idade;
    }
    function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }
    public $nome;
    private $sexo;
    private $idade;
}
class Amigo extends Pessoa {
    function __construct($nome, $sexo, $idade, $diaDoAniversario) {
        parent::__construct($nome, $sexo, $idade);
        $this->diaDoAniversario = $diaDoAniversario;
    }
    private $diaDoAniversario;
}

$joao = new Amigo("Jonis", "masc", 20, 30);
echo "Nome: {$joao->nome}";
echo "Nome: " . $joao->getNome();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eL6Pbj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ruohnqkr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Visibility.php).

Comment: Obrigado, realmente não forçar uma estrutura complexa dentro de uma string resolveu! Foi um exercício proposto pelo orientador a ser desenvolvido em php mesmo.. No mais é isso, valeu !!